# Automatically finding implicit type conversions (auto-boxing/auto-unboxing)

Tags: java, netbeans, sonarlint

I've inherited a project where "identical" instance variables are used inconsistently. For example in some classes they are stored as the primitive `float`:

```java
class Primitive {
  float myPrimitiveFloat;
  ...
}
```

..and in other classes, when the "same" variable is passed into the constructor, the value is stored as the boxed type Float:

```java
class Boxed {
  Float myBoxedFloat;
  ...
  Boxed(Float myFloat, .. ) {
    this.myFloat = myFloat;
  }
}
```

..and then calling `new Boxed(myPrimitiveFloat, ..)` from a method in `Primitive`.

I'm using `float`/`Float` as examples here, but this inconsistency could be any of the other couples too: `byte`/`Byte`, `short`/`Short`, `int`/`Integer`, `long`/`Long` `double`/`Double`, `boolean`/`Boolean` and `char`/`Char`.

I find it would be consistent if the type would be either the primitive `float` or the boxed type `Float` for the "same" variable, and I am looking for a way of examining the source code, without having to visit each file individually.

As examples the things I'd like to be looking for is when a `float` being passed when a `Float` is required or vice versa. That could be (the list is not exhaustive, there could be others):

- A call to a constructor (`new MyClass(..)`) using a variable of a type that is opposite to the type in the constructor.
- When the passed in parameter to a setter is opposite to the parameter of the method, as in `setMyVaribale(..)`
- When a getter is returning the opposite to the instance variable type it's getting. Like `float getMyValue()` where the class stores `myValue` as a `Float`.

My local Java editor/toolkit is NetBeans and its internal type checker is Sonar lint. I'm discouraged from using software that is deemed "not standard" by my company. This includes the Eclipse IDE.

The Development envrionment is Java version 11.

Is there any way of configuring Sonar lint or NetBeans to detect this sort of thing, or possible detect it while building using Maven/Gradle?

Generate a log file that could be used as input to an audit review would be useful as well.

Comment: Is this a Java question? In Java, the [`Float` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) is a wrapper for the primitive type. I can't see how that could lead to precision loss. (If you're talking about other language please let us know.)

Comment: I had assumed the change from float to the Float class would require the allocation of resources, since there seems to be a lot of float to Float and then back to float I assumed  I might get after microseconds more if I removed all this type of tripe.

I have added the Java label to the question, thanks for pointing out this detail

Comment: Precision or performance?

Comment: both are important

Comment: The issues raised in the question have been resolved using the method listed in the answer section.   

Some decimal precision issues were discovered during a currency conversion. The offending type was changed to a BigDecimal  which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to add a `report` section to the POM file. When building with `mvn site` (it can take a while), an HTML page (`target/site/index.html`) or an XML file (`target/spotbugsXml.xml`) describing the issues will be generated.

Anything tagged with the pattern `Bx:` indicates the use of a dubious programming issue using boxing/unboxing from the spotbugs viewpoint.

The XML file could be used as input for an audit trail review.

The reporting section described below also invokes some other static code analysis tools which may also indicate other issues which might need to be resolved.

```
 <reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-project-info.version}</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>index</report>
                        <report>ci-management</report> 
                        <report>dependencies</report>
                        <report>dependency-convergence</report>
                        <report>dependency-info</report>
                        <report>dependency-management</report>
                        <report>distribution-management</report>
                        <report>issue-management</report>
                        <report>licenses</report>
                        <report>mailing-lists</report>
                        <report>modules</report>
                        <report>plugin-management</report>
                        <report>plugins</report>
                        <report>scm</report>
                        <report>summary</report>
                        <report>team</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <effort>Max</effort>
                <threshold>low</threshold>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <id>html</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <doctitle>My API for ${project.name} ${project.version}</doctitle>
                        <windowtitle>My API for ${project.name} ${project.version}</windowtitle>
                    </configuration>
                    <reports>
                        <report>javadoc</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
                <reportSet>
                    <id>test-html</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <testDoctitle>My Test API for ${project.name} ${project.version}</testDoctitle>
                        <testWindowtitle>My Test API for ${project.name} ${project.version}</testWindowtitle>
                    </configuration>
                    <reports>
                        <report>test-javadoc</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

An entry of the spotbugs Maven page suggests that this is only guaranteed to work with Java 8. This code has been tested with Java version 8 and 11 and no problems were encountered.

More information about spotbugs can be found at [Spotbugs maven plugin](https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/)